# how to add or remove editeTextview in viewpager view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Below is my screenshot and when click on plus button then add one radio button and edit text view in view.

```
MyAdapter myAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

 myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);

   public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return new Fragment_question();

            //return Fragment_question.newInstance(position);
            // return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PreferenceManager.Constant.create_q_array.length();
        }
    }

public static class Fragment_question extends Fragment {

   @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pageradapter, container, false);
            findViewbyid(rootView);
            return rootView;

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create one instance in your Question Fragment and add your childView like below

```
public class Fragment_question extends Fragment {

  private View parentView;
  private LinearLayout linearLayout;

  @Override public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Nullable @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_xml, container, false);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) parentView.findViewById(R.id.question_layout);
    return parentView;
  }
```

> // In button Click add the view

```
  private void addEditText() {
    View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.editext_view, null);
    linearLayout.addView(view);
  }
}
```